# Borrowing error while trying to read JSON from stdin

Tags: json, rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to parse JSON line-by-line from stdin using the [pom](https://github.com/J-F-Liu/pom) library.

I've stolen the `json` implementation provided on the homepage (and have omitted that code below; it's not relevant), and am getting a borrow error from the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    for line in io::stdin().lock().lines() {
        let line2 = line.unwrap().as_bytes();
        let _value = json().parse(line2).unwrap();
    }
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:73:23
   |
73 |         let tmpline = line.unwrap().as_bytes();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------ temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                       |
   |                       creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |                       argument requires that borrow lasts for `'static`
```

[`.parse`](https://docs.rs/pom/3.0.2/pom/parser/struct.Parser.html#method.parse) in the pom libray has the type:

```rust
pub fn parse(&self, input: &'a [I]) -> Result<O>
```

[`.as_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_bytes) has the type:

```rust
pub fn as_bytes(&self) -> &[u8]
```

Obviously, I'm borrowing incorrectly here, but I'm not entirely sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're using a reference to a value whose lifetime is shorter than you need, and lies in this line: `line.unwrap().as_bytes()`.

`as_bytes()` returns a reference to the underlying slice of `u8`s. Now, that underlying slice, returned by `unwrap()`, happens to be a temporary which will die at the end of the statement.

In Rust, you can re-declare variables with the same name in the current scope and they will shadow the one(s) previously defined. To fix the problem, store the value somewhere, *and then* get a reference to it. Like so:

```
fn main() {
    for line in io::stdin().lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        let bytes = line.as_bytes();
        let _value = json().parse(bytes).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Now the value returned by `as_bytes()` can point to something that lives as long as the current scope. Previously, instead, you had this:

```
fn main() {
    for line in io::stdin().lock().lines() {
        let line2 = line.unwrap().as_bytes(); // <-- the value returned by unwrap dies here
        let _value = json().parse(line2).unwrap(); // <-- line2 would be dangling here
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your code, I get `line does not live long enough; .borrowed value does not live long enough; argument requires that line is borrowed for 'static` on the `let bytes = line.as_bytes()` line. Maybe it has something to do with the function signature of what `json().parse()` expects?

Answer (score 0):

`line.unwrap()` returns a `String`, which you then borrow from with `as_bytes()`. Since you never bind the `String` itself, only the borrowed byte slice, the `String` is dropped at the end of the statement, and the borrowed byte slice is invalidated.

Bind the temporary `String` to a variable with `let s = line.unwrap()`, then pass `s.as_bytes()` to `json().parse`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. I get`borrowed value does not live long enough`.

Comment: This is separate issue which occurs `json()` is returning a  `Parser<'static, ...>` when you need your parser to be variant over lifetimes. The [example code](https://github.com/J-F-Liu/pom/blob/master/examples/json.rs) returns such a `Parser`. You'll need to change your `json()` function to be generic over a lifetime as well.